# live555 low-latency video stream from ffmpeg encoder

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, live555

I'm trying to implement a application that stream video from my webcam via rtsp. I've done with part that encode from webcam to h264 video.

I'm trying to use live555 as streaming server, but I can't find any good examples or documentation to use it. Also the code don't have much commends.

Can anyone give some? Or other library good for that purpose.

Comment: Check out this mailing list post and its reply (from 2005!): http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2005-September/003133.html involving extending the DeviceSource class (http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/doxygen/html/classDeviceSource.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a low-latency RTSP server that capture an H264 stream from V4L2 interface from my GitHub project [v4l2rtspserver](https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver).

From your application that capture the webcam and encode frames using H264 encoder, it is not difficult to post it to the RTSP streamer.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in that I want to stream input taken from a camera and encoded using a DSP Processor. I'm having trouble writing a device source that would serve my purpose. Is there any way I can contact you for help.

Comment: You probably need a thread that activate a trigger in order to signal to live555 mainloop that a new frame should be send. If you post a question, I will try to answer it.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042716/stream-from-ip-camera-very-jittery-on-vlc . I'll be grateful.